# @angular/common/http/testing TestRequest.flush a boolean value

Tags: angular, typescript, http, mocking, boolean

I want to test use of an endpoint that will return `true` or `false` as the response. Not `'true'` but a boolean value of `true`. I am using the `@angular/common/http/testing` module. For other response values I can use `TestResponse.flush(value)`, but this does not work for a `boolean` value. Instead, the testing module complains

> Automatic conversion to JSON is not supported for response type.

---

Here is my test code:

```
const FLUSH_OK = {status: 200, statusText: 'Ok'};

//.. describe...
it('should work', async(() => {
  service.myFunction().subscribe((data) => { // my Function returns Observable<boolean>, the real endpoint returns a true/false boolean
    expect(data).toEqual(true);
  });

  // this fails: Failed: Automatic conversion to JSON is not supported for response type.
  httpMock.expectOne((req) => {
    return req.url === MY_URL;
  }).flush(true, FLUSH_OK);

 // this also fails: Expected 'true' to equal true.
 // httpMock.expectOne((req) => {
 //   return req.url === MY_URL;
 // }).flush('true', FLUSH_OK);

}));
```

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20690 ?

Comment: Oh, yeah... well, there it is.

Comment: That does seem to give this error though: Argument of type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<boolean>'.
  Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'ObjectContaining<boolean>'.

Comment: This is recognized as a bug in the testing module, and was fixed on 2020-10-05: see  [angular issue 37893](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/37893).

Answer (score 13):

Using the `event` method rather than `flush` allows you to specify the type of the response body.

```
const req = httpMock.expectOne('some-url');
req.event(new HttpResponse<boolean>({body: true}));
```

You could optionally also set other properties such as `status` or `statusText`.

[HttpResponse docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse)

[Original answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20690#issuecomment-389492155)